# How can I make keyboard shortcuts register on key release, rather than on key press?

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xfce, xfce-panel

I want to have shortcuts like in Windows; <kbd>Super</kbd> opens the start menu, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> opens a search window, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> opens `Thunar`, etc.

I know how to set keyboard shortcuts, but when I set <kbd>Super</kbd> to open `whiskermenu`, `whiskermenu` also pops up in every other instance of <kbd>Super</kbd>+* shortcuts. I think this is because XFCE registers the shortcuts as they come, rather than waiting for simultaneous release (like in Windows).

How do I set that up?

Comment: Have you resolved this ?

Comment: No I have not. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I have the same problem, I hope we can find a solution for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:**

1. **Install `xbindkeys`**

   ```
   sudo apt install xbindkeys
   ```
2. **Run the command:**

   ```
   xbindkeys --key
   ```

   In the white box that appears, Press your key combination. Example <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> will return the following :

   ```
   "(Scheme function)"
       m:0x50 + c:26
       Mod2+Mod4 + e
   ```

   Now copy the last (or last second) line and use it as given below.

   In newer versions before you need to do this, which let you jump the next step:

   > Please, create one with '`xbindkeys --defaults > /home/$USER/.xbindkeysrc`'.
   > or, if you want scheme configuration style,
   > with '`xbindkeys --defaults-guile > /home/$USER/.xbindkeysrc.scm`'
3. **Create a new file `.xbindkeysrc`** in your home Directory

   ```
   touch $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   Open it

   ```
   nano $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
   ```

   Enter your required command and keys as given below

   ```
   "nautilus"
       release+Mod2+Mod4 + e
   ```

   (**Note**: Don't forget `release` , Replace "nautilus" with any command.)

   Similarly add all the requires command-key combinations one below the other
4. **Now add `xbindkeys` to `xinitrc`:**

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
   ```

   add `xbindkeys` to the starting (1st line or before `. /etc/X11/Xsession`)

Reboot your system and you should get expected behavior

**TIP**: Make sure you don't set conflicting configurations in xbindkeys and your GUI method provided by your DE

For more examples, [`man xbindkeys`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xbindkeys.1.html).

Comment: I'm no longer on Xubuntu or even XFCE, but will try and spin up a VM to test this. Thanks for taking the time to answer; I thought I would never get one!

Comment: Will not work on Wayland

Comment: archwiki says that xinitrc is only for manual startup of xorg and xprofile is for ones with display managers. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by install patched XOrg

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: PPAs are not safe in general, I'd recommend against this for safety reasons.