# Super key release for whiskermenu

Tags: xubuntu, whisker

How to set <kbd>Super</kbd> key (**release**) as a shortcut for **`xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`**. Its currently set to <kbd>Ctrl/primary</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>.

I am using Xubuntu 16.04

Comment: Strange - I have Xubuntu 16.04 and I have the Super shortcut key set by default

Comment: @BharadwajRaju, I've tested it now in Virtualbox and it doesn't work by default

Comment: I think this may be similar to this unanswered question for it to work on key release instead of key press. http://askubuntu.com/questions/670209/how-can-i-make-keyboard-shortcuts-register-on-key-release-rather-than-on-key-pr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make keyboard shortcuts register on key release, rather than on key press?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670209/how-can-i-make-keyboard-shortcuts-register-on-key-release-rather-than-on-key-pr)

Answer (score 10):

Open whiskermenu, type "keyboard" and hit enter. Then choose "Shortcut for application" and find the entry for xfce4-popup-whiskermenu. Dubble-click the assigned shortcut. Now press Super-key. Done.

Comment: I tried it, but it sets for "Key press" not "Key release" i.e, If i want to use Super+R , it opens both whisker and something else

Answer (score 4):

[This thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237139/how-to-bind-the-super-key-to-whiskermenu-without-breaking-superother-combinatio) answers this question in a way that still allows using e.g. Super+E to open the file manager.

Basically for Xubuntu:

- `sudo apt install -y xcape`
- click the menu button, find "Session and Startup" and add a new entry in the "Application Autostart" tab. Use any name you like and put this in the Command field:

  `xcape -e 'Super_L=Shift_L|Control_L|Alt_L|Super_L|D'`
  It's remapping the Super key to another, more complicated shortcut that 's unlikely to be used.
- assign the same complicated key combination to `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu` in the standard shortcut manager (click menu, type "keyboard", press Enter, the rest should be obvious)