# How to bind the super/mod/windows key to a custom command

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I tried to add it in the default shortcuts application but it just won't accept <kbd>super</kbd> on it's own. It will accept <kbd>Super + X</kbd> But I just want to override the super key.

I'm using Mate so no Unity conflict.

I tried searching and did found a few very specific work around but none with the super key and a custom command/script.

Example what I want is:

**Press** <kbd>Super</kbd>
**Do** `bash ~/rearange_windows.sh --all`

Comment: Make sure that Super key isn't used, for MENU maybe,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use `xbindkeys`](https://askubuntu.com/a/831899/331270)

Put your command with a "release" event into `~/xbindkeysrc`.

For more info, see `man xbindkeys`.

Comment: I did get it to work with `super+e` but nothing I tried will trigger the `super` action I defined. It's not bound to any other action currently. I tried multiple annotations which worked for `super+e`.  Also when googleing _'xbindkeys windows'_ and related I can't find anything.

Comment: Please edit your post with the contents of ~/xbindkeysrc.

Comment: I got it `Mod2+Mod4 + e` = `super+e` but normal super is just plain old `Super_L`

Comment: You should try binding both Super_L and Mod2+Mod4 to the script.

Comment: I tried `Mod2+Mod4 + Super_L` and `Mod2+Mod4` solo both didn't work. But like I said I got it working

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @ijustlovemath, yes, you can use `xbindkeys`, but I suggest a different format for your command.

Add this to `~/xbindkeysrc`:

```
"xte 'keydown Super_L' 'key e' 'keyup Super_L'"
   bash ~/rearange_windows.sh --all
```